# Silverlight - Change Font Size of Data Grid Header in C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

I am trying to change the font size of the data grid header content in the C# code behind as follows:

```
this.DataGrid_CardDetails.ColumnHeaderStyle.Setters.SetValue(FontSize, 26);
```

Unfortunately, it is giving me the following error:

```
cannot convert from 'double' to 'System.Windows.DependencyProperty'
```

How can I solve this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can modify a style like that.  Instead, make a new one and apply it:

```
Style s = new Style(typeof(DataGridColumnHeader));
s.BasedOn = this.DataGrid_CardDetails.ColumnHeaderStyle;
s.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridColumnHeader.FontSizeProperty, 26));

this.DataGrid_CardDetails.ColumnHeaderStyle = s;
```

Comment: Thank you so much :))))))  I have been stuck on this problem for hours :) Thank you so much :))))

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do this on more than one grid, you can create a style in XAML in a ResourceDictionary and apply it throughout your app (or even if it's just this one grid, and you'd rather set the style in XAML than code-behind, which I definitely prefer).